# I have a list, and I get errors when trying to write the list's content to a text file. Why and how do I fix it? (C#)

Tags: c#, list, io

I have a list whose contents show up just fine in my dataGrid with this code:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = lstExample;
```

This tells me my List is fine, and when I view the dataGrid it has all the data I need.  But when I try to output the same List to a text file with this code:

```
string output = @"C:\output.txt";
File.WriteAllLines(output, lstExample);
```

I get this error:

```
Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: What is the type of List? WriteAllLines expects IEnumerable<string> but List isn't that type.

Comment: What format you'd like the list to be written in file. and post the code where you generate the list

Comment: I hope that your real List name is not List. See the confusion here?

Comment: @Steve It appears to be a list of some anonymous type

Comment: @Steve Yeah, let's assume the real list name, for purposes of this example, is lstExample.

Comment: @ Sriram Sakthivel.  The code to generate the list is complicated and long and I was hoping to avoid having to post it. Is there a quick fix to convert a list of any type into a IE<string>?  Or, is there another command that will let me output my existing list to a text file?  My goal is simply to put the contents of my list into a text file, and I am not attached to using any particular command.

Comment: Another messier approach (that I don't know how to do) is to perhaps print the contents of my DataGrid to a text file, because the dataGrid displays the contents of my lstExample quite nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example that shows what you have to do with your list:

```
List<int> lst = new List<int>();
lst.Add(1);
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\1\text.txt", lst.Select( i => i.ToString()));
```

simply you have to cast your anonymous type to string some how (maybe it would be string.Format("{0} {1}", i.A, i.B);

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("output.txt");                       
tw.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", lstExample));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just like to convert the anonymous type to string this would help.

```
File.WriteAllLines(output, lstExample.Select(x=>x.ToString()));
```

If this is not enough then you have to provide more info about how you need your output to be and how that anonymous type is defined etc

Comment: Thanks Sriram, I appreciate your help.  You and Georgy had identical responses and I chose his only because he was first in time.